# Do not populate and hide the drop-down if no options are present using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having 3 `drop-downs` `Drop-down A`,`Drop-down B`,`Drop-down C`. 
Based on the selection of `DropDown C`, few more dropdowns will be populated.

Lets say we have another 10 drop-downs numbered from 1 to 10, that are going to be populated on the selection of `Drop-down C`.

- When I select `item 1` from the `Dropdown C`, then `DropDown 1,2,4,6` should be populated and displayed on the page.
- When I select `item 2` from the `Dropdown C`, then `DropDown 1,2,5,6,8` should be populated and displayed on the page.

*In similar fashion I have many scenarios.*


Once required `Dropdowns` are populated and displayed on the page, then on posting only selected dropdown values should be saved on the Db.

*Also if any `dropdown` does not contain any option, then it should not appear on the page.*

*Jsfiddle link :* [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/15761/) 

How can I do it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your requirement in your controller and based on that you could toggle the dropdown show/hide:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.opt1 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt2 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt3 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt4 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt5 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt6 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt7 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
   $scope.opt8 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt9 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    $scope.opt10 = ["opt1", "opt2"];
    
    $scope.showDropDownOptions = [];
    $scope.showDropDownOptions[0] = [2,3,6];
    $scope.showDropDownOptions[1] = [1,4];
    $scope.showDropDownOptions[2] = [5,9,10,7];
    $scope.showDropDownOptions[3] = [8];
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <select name="main" id="main">
    <option value="mainOption">mainOption1</option>
    <option value="mainOption">mainOption2</option>
    <option value="mainOption">mainOption3</option>
    <option value="mainOption">mainOption4</option>
  </select>
    <hr>
    <select name="sub" id="main">
    <option value="subOption">subOption1</option>
    <option value="subOption">subOption2</option>
    <option value="subOption">subOption3</option>
    <option value="subOption">subOption4</option>
  </select>
    <hr>
    <select ng-model="selectC" name="subSub" id="main">
    <option value="0">subSubOption1</option>
    <option value="1">subSubOption2</option>
    <option value="2">subSubOption3</option>
    <option value="3">subSubOption4</option>
  </select>

    <hr>
    <select ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(1) != '-1' && selectC && opt1.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt1">
  </select>
    <select ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(2) != '-1' && selectC && opt2.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt2">
  </select>
    <select ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(3) != '-1' && selectC && opt3.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt3">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(4) != '-1' && selectC && opt4.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt4">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(5) != '-1' && selectC && opt5.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt5">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(6) != '-1' && selectC && opt6.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt6">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(7) != '-1' && selectC && opt7.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt7">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(8) != '-1' && selectC && opt8.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt8">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(9) != '-1' && selectC && opt9.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt9">
  </select>
    <select  ng-if="showDropDownOptions[selectC].indexOf(10) != '-1' && selectC && opt10.length>0" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in opt10">
  </select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if any `dropdown` list is empty, in that case it should not appear on the page.

Comment: @mayankbisht updated my answer according to your requirement.

Comment: Again, thanks for updating the answer. I tried your code in plunker, just wanted to print the selected dropDown list value, but it's not showing.
`Plunker link:` `https://plnkr.co/edit/yEx3fOz9lBY9MQyffnH5?p=preview`

Comment: I checked out your plnkr, what is the problem your are facing?

Comment: `Test Model: {{selectedNamelast}}` this statement is not working in plunker.

Comment: you have disabled this model by assigning empty value to opt10. thats why its not coming in DOM.

Comment: I am testing for ` $scope.showDropDownOptions[3] = [8,10];`, [8] contains 2 options, whereas [10] is empty, so I want [8] options to be printed.

Comment: [8] ng-model name is: selectedName22, and you are testing with selectedNamelast

Comment: my bad, i have changed it to `selectedName22` but still getting as empty.

Comment: oh okay.
yeah, now it's working.
But see, there is one problem, even when I change my option still Test Model value:opt2 is showing.

Comment: You have to code it further according to your requirement, in this case you clear everything on ng-change

Comment: Okay, just now I read about `ng-change`. So I'll call one method and pass current `ng-model` value, then in controller i'll assign `null` to other model values. Is my logic correct, or do you see an other better solution for this?

Comment: just do $scope.obj = {}, in ng-change and it will work, since every ng-modle is property of $scope.obj.

Comment: yes, its difficult to solve all your business logic to one answer.

Comment: I just want to see current selected dropdown values, for example on first item selection, values from `dropdown1 , 2 ,4` should be displayed.